# Typesetting symbols like "ΔF" in TraditionalForm

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, I'm plotting a function with an axis labeled by "ΔF". As is typical for Mathematica, TraditionalForm gets wrapped around ΔF before it is displayed. The trouble is that this label looks out of place, as it isn't italicized like other symbols on the plot that are composed of single characters. Is there a way to force TraditionalForm to italicize ΔF? I have tried using ┆is┆ `(\[InvisibleSpace])`, but that gets displayed as *`F Δ`* instead, which is not what I intended. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you post the example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
ListLinePlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, AxesLabel -> Row[{\[CapitalDelta], F}]]
```

Comment: Just curious ... Do you see any difference between how this one and the "Style" solution are shown?

Comment: @belisarius: Yeah, the Δ is not italicized in my answer... Put them side-to-side using `AxesLabel -> 
 Row[{\[CapitalDelta], F, "=", Style["\[CapitalDelta]F", Italic]}]` and it becomes clear.

Comment: Oh well ... I might go for new lenses :D

Comment: Ah, that matches quite nicely what I was hoping to use \\[InvisibleSpace] to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Not completely sure that this is what you want, but anyway ...

Try

```
ListLinePlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}},
 AxesLabel -> Style["\[CapitalDelta]F", Italic]]
```

Comment: It's not precisely, but it is a very nice workaround, so thank you! I just wish that Mathematica exposed a way to make a compound symbol without having to sidestep TraditionalForm entirely.